# How to Get multiple value from clicking item on listview android studio

Tags: android, listview

I need to get value from listview, but i can't find any solutions yet, I create listview to look like a table, and want to get the value when i click the row/listview item

here my code:

**1. Bill.java**

```
public class Bill {

    private int _id;
    private String _bill_no;
    private String _type;
    private String _table;
    private int _qty;
    private String _amount;
    private String _status;

    public Bill() {

    }

    public Bill(int id, String bill_no, String type, String table, int qty, String amount, String status) {
        this._id = id;
        this._bill_no = bill_no;
        this._type = type;
        this._table = table;
        this._qty = qty;
        this._amount = amount;
        this._status = status;
    }

    public Bill(String bill_no, String type, String table, int qty, String amount, String status) {
        this._bill_no = bill_no;
        this._type = type;
        this._table = table;
        this._qty = qty;
        this._amount = amount;
        this._status = status;
    }

    public int getID() {
        return this._id;
    }
    public void setID(int id) {
        this._id = id;
    }

    public String get_bill_no()
    {
        return this._bill_no;
    }
    public void set_bill_no(String bill_no)
    {
        this._bill_no = bill_no;
    }

    public String get_type()
    {
        return this._type;
    }
    public void set_type(String type)
    {
        this._type = type;
    }

    public String get_table()
    {
        return this._table;
    }
    public void set_table(String table)
    {
        this._table = table;
    }

    public int get_qty()
    {
        return this._qty;
    }
    public void set_qty(int qty)
    {
        this._qty = qty;
    }

    public String get_amount()
    {
        return this._amount;
    }
    public void set_amount(String amount)
    {
        this._amount = amount;
    }

    public String get_status()
    {
        return this._status;
    }
    public void set_status(String status)
    {
        this._status = status;
    }

}
```

**2.BillListAdapter.java**

```
public class BillListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<Bill> listData;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public BillListAdapter(Context aContext, ArrayList<Bill> listData) {
        this.listData = listData;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(aContext);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return listData.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listData.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_bill_layout, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.txtBillNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillId);
            holder.txtBillNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillNo);
            holder.txtBillType = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillType);
            holder.txtBillTable = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillTable);
            holder.txtBillQty = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillQty);
            holder.txtBillAmount = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillAmount);
            holder.txtBillStatus = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.txtBillStatus);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.txtBillId.setText(listData.get(position).getID());
        holder.txtBillNo.setText(listData.get(position).get_bill_no());
        holder.txtBillType.setText(listData.get(position).get_type());
        holder.txtBillTable.setText(listData.get(position).get_table());
        //holder.txtBillQty.setText(listData.get(position).get_qty());
        holder.txtBillAmount.setText(listData.get(position).get_amount());
        holder.txtBillStatus.setText(listData.get(position).get_status());

        return convertView;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView txtBillId;
        TextView txtBillNo;
        TextView txtBillType;
        TextView txtBillTable;
        TextView txtBillQty;
        TextView txtBillAmount;
        TextView txtBillStatus;
    }
}
```

**3. list_bill_layout.xml (item that looped)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:id="@+id/txtBillNo"
        android:text="Bill No"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtBillType"
        android:text="Bill Type"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

    <TextView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtBillTable"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtBillQty"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        android:text="0"
         />

    <TextView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtBillAmount"
        android:text="Amount"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
         />

    <TextView

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtBillStatus"
        android:text="Status"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="14dp"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:background="#EEE"
        android:textColor="#333"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:id="@+id/txtBillDate"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

**4.1. Index.java snippet of ListView**

```
ArrayList list_bill = getListBill();
        final ListView listview_bill = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.order_listing);
        listview_bill.setAdapter(new BillListAdapter(this, list_bill));

        listview_bill.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                //how to get the value ?
                Log.d(TAG, "click bill");

            }
        });
```

**4.2 Index.java snippet of function getListBill()**

```
private ArrayList getListBill()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase mydatabase = openOrCreateDatabase("posDb",MODE_PRIVATE,null);
        Cursor resultSet = mydatabase.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bills",null);

        ArrayList<Bill> results = new ArrayList<Bill>();

        if (resultSet.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                Bill billsData = new Bill();
                billsData.set_bill_no(resultSet.getString(1));
                billsData.set_type(resultSet.getString(2));
                billsData.set_table(resultSet.getString(3));
                billsData.set_qty(resultSet.getInt(4));
                billsData.set_amount(resultSet.getString(5));
                billsData.set_status(resultSet.getString(6));

                //put them into results
                results.add(billsData);
            } while (resultSet.moveToNext());
        }

        return results;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get value like this:

```
ArrayList<Bill> list_bill = getListBill();
    final ListView listview_bill = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.order_listing);
    listview_bill.setAdapter(new BillListAdapter(this, list_bill));

    listview_bill.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
            //how to get the value ?
            Log.d(TAG, "click bill");
            Bill mBill = list_bill.get(position); 
            // Now you can get what you want from mBill object.

        }
    });

   //And in your getListBill method use ArrayList<Bill> instead of only ArrayList.
```

Comment: giving me error: Error:(83, 43) error: incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to Bill

Comment: it works! Thanks! @Piyush it drives me crazy before!

Answer (score 1):

The way is like following-

```
 listview_bill.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {
                   Bill billsData=(Bill ) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
                   //data= billsData.get_amount();
             }
     });
```

Comment: i tried this one: but got error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setText(int)' on a null object reference, 

here the snipper: 
Bill billsData = (Bill) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
                String bill_no = billsData.get_bill_no();
                Log.d(TAG, "click bill ID:"+ bill_no);
what was wrong?

Comment: BillListAdapter ba=new BillListAdapter(this, list_bill);
listview_bill.setAdapter(ba);
inside click try using like it
Bill billsData = ba.getItem(position);

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Bill bill = (Bill) a.getItemAtPosition(position);
```